# Error when running coxph on gene expression data

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I am getting an error when running  `coxph` on my data. Have anyone of you seen this before?

```
coxph(Surv(OS,Survival_dead0_alive1)~.,data=data.frame(Bind))

Error in fitter(X, Y, strats, offset, init, control, weights = weights,  : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 6)
In addition: Warning message:
In fitter(X, Y, strats, offset, init, control, weights = weights,  :
  Ran out of iterations and did not converge
```

My data:

```
> head(Bind)
    hsa-let-7a-5p hsa-let-7b-5p hsa-let-7f-5p hsa-let-7g-5p hsa-let-7i-5p hsa-miR-101-3p hsa-miR-103a-3p
020      8.525737      9.077023      8.380155      7.734305      9.724084       8.505507        9.952546
045     11.885240     10.680675     12.909627      9.659705     11.684750       9.501075       11.060350
080     11.922765      9.709317     12.937002      9.608698     11.027545       8.918902       10.198448
082     10.522788      9.800196     11.019010      9.017653     10.608756       9.116801       10.981711
084     14.398983     13.917347     15.950312     13.643770     14.849673      19.106340       16.381978
086     12.991248     10.526353     13.891862     10.216253     11.871303      10.267358       12.060968
    hsa-miR-106b-3p hsa-miR-107 hsa-miR-10a-5p hsa-miR-10b-5p hsa-miR-126-3p hsa-miR-126-5p hsa-miR-1307-5p
020        8.736831    9.913751       8.785006       9.509614       6.160457       9.568709        6.472602
045        9.669884   10.600395      12.072752      12.616410       9.841329      12.199432        9.835345
080        8.676124    9.745139      13.143389      14.097870       9.780005      12.678141        9.981547
082        9.479583   10.787869      11.212550      12.326868       7.600882       9.797073        8.937480
084       10.072361   16.327778      21.089233      16.415726      10.885272      15.550348       15.349871
086        9.722471   11.788772      12.815745      13.895031       9.928474      11.956818       10.526353
    hsa-miR-130a-3p hsa-miR-140-3p hsa-miR-141-3p hsa-miR-142-5p hsa-miR-143-3p hsa-miR-144-3p hsa-miR-144-5p
020        6.993426       7.063975       2.726202       10.83548       8.177073       6.984873       5.875895
045        8.700323       8.623106       4.258602       11.72496      11.017748       8.352795       7.199350
080        8.410844       7.129067       7.687576       11.53991       9.249907       8.753803       8.505378
082        7.368333       8.589622       3.899788       11.20649       9.622052       8.410481       7.349408
084       13.824029       9.881256       5.942495       12.49186      16.496929      12.346393      10.387328
086        8.748585       8.646370       5.992389       11.39576       9.960052       9.374619       9.451418
    hsa-miR-146b-5p hsa-miR-148a-3p hsa-miR-151a-3p hsa-miR-15a-5p hsa-miR-16-2-3p hsa-miR-16-5p hsa-miR-181a-5p
020        6.825487        8.935624        9.495543       10.02602        8.794871      13.70308        9.505791
045        7.506878       11.608944       12.364735       10.58655        9.783405      14.09747       12.248791
080        6.461902       11.315771       11.297933        9.99134        8.983739      12.79753       13.281242
082        5.765382       11.144908        9.497258       10.51729        9.056027      13.58097       12.631773
084       10.525156       25.006534       13.430802       16.22535       10.185384      17.70031       16.908886
086        6.438835       11.889882       11.091509       11.33448        9.552341      13.50666       13.578251
    hsa-miR-182-5p hsa-miR-186-5p hsa-miR-191-5p hsa-miR-192-5p hsa-miR-199a-3p hsa-miR-199b-3p hsa-miR-19a-3p
020       9.554027       10.55887       10.57660      10.059605        5.331217        5.331217       5.473092
045      10.017655       11.68161       13.00958      10.644459       10.574318       10.574318       6.284569
080       9.836127       11.09218       12.47866      11.009756        9.745139        9.745139       5.932696
082      10.211428       10.43197       11.69112      10.866778        8.361732        8.361732       5.938032
084      12.149268       15.05111       12.28892      22.162546       16.668760       16.668760      10.145723
086      10.300424       11.32269       12.31837       9.495561       10.011156       10.011156       6.305182
    hsa-miR-19b-3p hsa-miR-21-5p hsa-miR-22-3p hsa-miR-25-3p hsa-miR-26a-5p hsa-miR-26b-5p hsa-miR-27a-3p
020       7.080042      9.055677      12.95556      13.10529       9.069946       6.581722       6.882323
045       7.887126     12.328800      15.40046      12.92344      12.977058       9.321807      10.074278
080       6.942131     12.833538      14.09914      11.58682      13.133720       9.456343       9.879351
082       7.290994     10.615609      14.03497      12.77837      11.096663       7.799290       9.627379
084      12.074954     21.150996      26.76700      16.02596      15.937430      12.473736      14.947538
086       7.750132     12.580098      14.72288      12.65702      12.772796       9.466287      10.491131
    hsa-miR-27b-3p hsa-miR-29a-3p hsa-miR-30a-5p hsa-miR-30c-5p hsa-miR-30d-5p hsa-miR-30e-5p hsa-miR-320a hsa-miR-320b
020       9.222262       5.360835       7.503475       5.189058       11.73659       10.92572     7.714683     6.111557
045      12.030654       8.060408       9.922490      10.542361       13.85970       12.91382    10.349932     9.625221
080      11.618125       8.753803      10.747875      10.231342       12.67439       11.65418    10.347811     9.802744
082      10.319820       7.978314       9.475624       9.192182       12.14658       11.34347     9.547060     8.036919
084      23.451162      17.093151      18.631805       8.413819       16.01589       17.65584    18.486646    16.166823
086      10.875653       8.103078      10.476791      10.659025       13.05021       11.82513    11.141786    10.233496
    hsa-miR-3615 hsa-miR-375 hsa-miR-378a-3p hsa-miR-423-3p hsa-miR-423-5p hsa-miR-425-5p hsa-miR-451a hsa-miR-484
020     7.480079    6.491425        6.215312       8.705659       13.22919       9.868943     13.51664   10.042707
045     9.027042    8.174936        9.268583      12.656559       14.89358      10.940546     13.76140   11.108842
080     8.077681    9.825093        8.728419      11.246651       14.47793       9.931447     12.62325    9.900439
082     8.649305    7.910777        9.034232      10.986268       14.30074      10.004025     14.28673   10.770453
084     5.716977   14.013445       19.926417      17.625759       21.80929       8.468569     16.24687   11.286335
086     9.037216    6.673159       10.340692      11.833391       15.80876       9.874213     14.17999   11.132777
    hsa-miR-486-3p hsa-miR-486-5p hsa-miR-584-5p hsa-miR-660-5p hsa-miR-92a-3p hsa-miR-92b-3p hsa-miR-93-5p
020       7.593128       17.87764       6.936818       6.245665       14.81484       8.272820      9.909526
045       9.512490       17.73956       9.656295       7.049662       16.61683       9.286554     10.674161
080       8.077681       16.46870       9.065472       6.723940       15.73787      10.130069      9.004656
082       9.152502       17.92071       8.348126       6.928074       16.21035       7.917058      9.963153
084       5.750738       19.70099       7.238084      12.881830       20.27929       4.620864     11.917808
086       8.319596       18.18648      10.145087       7.937656       17.02111       8.698406     10.189986
    hsa-miR-99a-5p OS Survival_dead0_alive1
020       5.331217  6                     1
045       7.072067 11                     1
080       6.837582 29                     0
082       6.762251  2                     0
084      15.891079 40                     1
086       5.992389 40                     1
```

Comment: I don't know for sure and I could be wrong, but it could be that you have too few observations for the number of variables that you are using. Also, I wouldn't be surprised if some of your columns are causing multicollinearity. Could you do two things: (1) show `dim(Bind)`, (2) rerun the analysis with substantially fewer columns?

Comment: I works if I take part of the dataset. With 30 columns it works fine, however,  my whole dataset with 80 columns seems to be to large

Comment: Well, in that case I think you'd be better of asking this question on [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/), this seems more of a statistics kind of problem. It does seem that you are using too many variables for the number of observations/events, if you keep in mind the [one-in-ten rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_in_ten_rule). But since I haven't done survival analysis in a while, since no one else has replied so far, and since the people over at CrossValidated are very good at stats, I'd guess they can help you better :)

Comment: as in any regression model, you run into collinearity with a lot of predictors. another thing that you should take care of is to try to center the covariates to have mean 0. This is because in the estimation routine of the Cox model the covariates get exponentiated. Usually I recommend centering all continuous covariates.

Comment: Hi, did you get the solution for this problem? I am getting the same problem in my analysis.

Comment: Have you checked for missing values (NA) in your data? I would drop the NAs and refit the model.
As @slamballais mentioned, I also think the second warning message you received had come from too many covariates being in your model. 10 events per variable (EPV) is the usual rule of thumb: per 10 events you have in your data you can insert one covariate in your model.